# Detect when a component is loaded after *ngIf execution

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was trying to initialize members of a component thru @ViewChild decor who just have loaded, however it seems that the creation of the component is delayed, so i end up with non existing variable error.

sample parent component snippet :

```
{
   ...
   dependOnData = null;
   @ChildView('cview') child;
       setWidgetData(data) {
          dependOnData = new Object();
          child.stuff = data;
       }
    ...
 }
```

Sample parent component html:

```
  <app-childthing *ngIf="dependOnData !==null; else somethingelse"
    #cview>

  </app-childthing>

  <ng-template #soemthingelse>
....

  </ng-template>
```

So as you can see, cview child does not exist yet initially, but when i initialize dependOnData to something not null, it should be instantiated, yet i still get errors about child.stuff not existing.

any work arounds?

Comment: I'm assuming this is an Angular2 or greater project? If so - you should remove the angularjs tag as that's an entirely different framework.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith I just did :)

Comment: @j-dar-rodriguez are you trying to pass data to the child component or call a method on the child component? or?

Comment: Why not simply pass `stuff` to the child component via an `@Input` from the parent?

Comment: I assume that `@ChildView` should be `@ViewChild`.

Comment: I am trying to pass data to the the child, i want via input, THE PROBLEM IS THAT THE APP-CHILD THING DOES NOT EXIST YET BECAUSE OF ngIF, please pay attention.

Comment: You can pass data via input binding to your child even with the ngif, angular will handle it itself, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a @ViewChild, then use a setter and move your logic to the setter.

```
@ViewChild('cview') set child(child: ChildType) {
    if (child) {
        child.stuff = data;
   } 
}
```

Or pass the data directly to the child via an `Input`, angular will do the binding automatically:

```
<app-childthing [stuff]="data" *ngIf="dependOnData !==null; else somethingelse">
</app-childthing>

<ng-template #soemthingelse>
    ...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I know that, the problem is that initially app-childthing does not exist yet because of *ngIF so their is no object to refer on.

Comment: Yes I understand, this is why I use a setter in my answer

Comment: However I would go with an input binding as it is more simple.